# Java deserialization of old Object

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I'm having a problem when serializing and deserializing my objects in my project. I'm writing the object to a name.dat file.
However whenever i make a change in the Name class i can nolonger deserialize it, since it's two different objects.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: It's two different *classes*, and the error message tells you pretty much what you need to do.

Comment: This is exactly why Java's built-in serialization mechanism is not very well suited for long-term storage of data. Use a standard format such as XML or JSON for storing your data.

Answer (score 1):

Your best options are:

1. Don't change your classes :-)
2. Throw away any serialized objects each time you change your classes.
3. Don't use Java object serialization.

Given that 1) and 2) are probably out of the question, option 3) should be given serious consideration.  There a variety of alternatives to Java serialization, depending on the nature of the data you are persisting.  These include:

- Using Java properties files
- Storing the data in a classical database (using SQL and the JDBC API)
- Using an object-relational database mapping such as Hibernate
- Using XML or JSON and a "binding" technology so that you can serialize / deserialize POJOs.

---

Finally, it is possible to implement class versioning using Java object serialization.  However, it is tricky.  And if you are continually changing the classes, then it is not going to be pleasant.  Start by reading [Versioning of Serializable Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html).

Comment: 4. `static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` or whatever the old value was.

Comment: Yes ... until you make an incompatible change and it all goes pear-shaped.  So, really, no.

Comment: Tahnk you so much for this! Although it seems easier just to add static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; :)

Comment: @V.möller - It is certainly easier.  Until you get burned.